# Do I need to re-purchase software in the Ubuntu Software Centre if I reinstall?

Tags: software-center

I want to purchase the Fluendo DVD player using the Ubuntu Software Centre. If I reinstalled Ubuntu, would I have to purchase the software again?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you don't need to purchase it again.

If you want to install your previous purchages after reinstalling Ubuntu, just click on the *File -> Reinstall Previous Purchases* menu item in *Software Center*.

Comment: How does the Software Centre know the account?

Comment: You'll be prompted for your login details when you click it.